# Making Image edges tranparent while displaying

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage

I have an image which has a slight border on corners. While displaying this image in my table view cell, I am setting cell's background color as white. But the slight edge of the image is still visible. How can I rectify this.

See the sample image.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Crop the image or edit out the border?  Since the discoloration is actually present in the original image, I don't see how you are going to get rid of it with code.

(Of course, the cropping and editing could be done in code, but if this is a standard asset, you ought to process it before inclusion in your app so that you don't waste CPU/GPU cycles and energy doing unnecessary image processing.)